# Can I have IIS rewrite rules write to a file?

Tags: iis, regular-expressions

Extendng on my question at [Is it possible to write a regular expression that catches a match that others have missed in IIS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/289589/is-it-possible-to-write-a-regular-expression-that-catches-a-match-that-others-hav) I would like to know if I can have the rewrite rules write to a file. For example if the file test.aspx is not found and rather than redirecting the user, it gets logged into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS URl Rewrite can load custom providers so it's possible to do this using your own provider. For more information see:

> [Developing a Custom Rewrite Provider for URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/804/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module/)
>
> [Using Custom Rewrite Providers with URL Rewrite Module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/803/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module/)

Although it might be easier to trawl the IIS logs for 404 errors or have a customer 404 page to do this for you.

Comment: Thanks Kev. So there is no way to do it without the Providers? The reason being is that we are on a shared hosting environment and I highly doubt they will install the providers for us.

Comment: @peanuts - there's no built in mechanism to write to file "out of the box". However you shouldn't need your hoster to install the providers. Just drop them in your /bin folder and reference them in the `web.config` file as described in the articles.

Comment: Which files do I need to include in the /bin folder?

Comment: You have to write the provider yourself then deploy the compiled binaries into the /bin folder of your website.

Comment: Ah, according to the articles I could do them via IIS hence my assumption I could copy across the Provider assemblies into the bin folder and reference them from there. Unfortunately I am not a .NET developer. Is there any other way?

Comment: Unfortunately you need to roll your sleeves up and start cutting code. Not helpful I know, but have a Google around and see if someone else has written a provider.